# virsh begin-backup — Unable to validate doc …/domainbackup.rng

Tags: backup, libvirt

I am trying to create a backup of a given VM in »push mode« as described [here](https://libvirt.org/formatbackup.html). I have tried a lot of variations of the backup-xml but none passes the validation test. That includes the example posted [here (the first one)](https://libvirt.org/formatbackup.html#examples). Additionally I just ran that command:

```
sudo virsh backup-begin vm1 && sudo virsh backup-dumpxml vm1
```

which dumps the autogenerated XML of the backup job with default values. In my case that looks like that:

```
<domainbackup mode='push'>
  <disks>
    <disk name='vda' backup='yes' type='file' backupmode='full' index='4'>
      <driver type='qcow2'/>
      <target file='/home/xxx/.local/share/libvirt/images/vm1.qcow2.1684137281'/>
    </disk>
    <disk name='sda' backup='no'/>
  </disks>
</domainbackup>
```

So I put that output in a file (`bg.xml`) and ran: `sudo virsh backup-begin vm1 ./bg.xml` which than again showed the error:

```
error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domainbackup.rng
Extra element disks in interleave
Element domainbackup failed to validate content
```

Any Idea what is going wrong here - since the auto-generated content fails validation I am getting out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this on IRC so for completness:

The problem is the 'index="4"' part, which is an output-only element and thus not allowed by the schema on input. The rest of the XML is correct.